# Apply Textbox Style to Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox, styles, controls

I'm New to Wpf and trying to learn using web based tutorials

I have created a Control (Class) Name **MyTextBox** which is inherited from **TextBox**

```
Public Class MyTextBox
       Inherits TextBox
.
.
End Class
```

I have created a **Style** for **TextBox** in **Application.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I Add MyTextBox to my Form and run it, the above style applies to TextBox Control but there is No Effect on MyTextBox Control

Please Tell my How to Solve This

Amit Saraf

Comment: change the target type to your control `<Style TargetType="MyTextBox">`

Comment: I get this err Error **MyTextBox is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.**

Answer (score 1):

You should considered reading more about wpf or buying a book.

The style has defined the target type being TextBox.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
```

That is why all elements of type TextBox will have that certain style.

MyTextBox has the type name "MyTextBox" and has nothing to do with TextBox when styling.

WPF compares type names but not base type names.

Else applying style to type "Control" would make the WPF change every Button, TextBox, Labe, ListBox, Border... Every control in WPF inherits from base Control class. That would screw things up, don't you think?

However you can use the keyword BasedOn to specify that your MyTextBox has its style based on something else.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx